# Use only specifics exit nodes for a site

Tags: exit-relays

In torrc, with `AllowDotExit` and `MapAddress` i can specify only one exit node for "mysite.com".
For example with:

> AllowDotExit 1
>
> MapAddress mysite.com mysite.com.mynode.exit

With `ExitNodes` and `StrictNodes` i can specify ten exit nodes but for all sites. For example with:

> StrictNodes 1
>
> ExitNodes mynode1, mynode2, ... mynode10

---

I want that for "mysite.com" tor use only ten exit node that i specify in torrc and for others sites use all exit nodes.
How can i do this?